# keyboardView with webview

Tags: android, webview, keyboard, custom-keyboard

I´m working on a custom **system** keyboard based on this [tutorial](https://www.ssaurel.com/blog/learn-to-create-a-system-keyboard-on-android/). Which creates a basic custom keyboard. How would I be able to add a webview over the keyboard? Basically I want a small row [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCh0O.jpg) on top of the keyboard, but instead emojis, I want a (small) webview to be there.

I have tried to add a webview decleration in the *number_pad* file without it making any differanse, tried the same with *keyboard_view*, but it also din´t work. I tried to change webview to textview to see if it would show anything then, but still nothing. Then I thought I might be able to use a popupWindow, but I wasn't able to get that to work either :/.

Any ideas? Any tips? i´m new to android programing so a little code POC with the answer would be nice.

Comment: From a privacy and security standpoint, having a Web browser embedded in an input method editor is positively frightening.

Comment: Well it will be for my personal project and it will not load the content for webview from an online recourse. So regarding security, there exist worse problems. Regarding privacy, Android is brewed at Google.